# Dynamic changing of "src" in image VUE

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am trying to generate `src` link to each of my `li` items generated by `v-for`.

I have list of some Strings... `["Electronics","Furniture", "Cloths", "Sports", "Entertainment", "Others"]` and in each tag

I want to generate some  with dynamically changing `src`.

For example:
First item is electronics so path would be `@/assets/Electronics.png` and image would be displayed
Second item is Furniture so path would be `@/assets/Furniture.png`

What do I need to do to show that `img` how do I need to define this **path**?

```
<ul class="menu-dropdown">
   <li v-for="item in items" :key="item" class="center align-self-center">
      <img class="float-left" :src="getPicture(item)" v-bind:alt="item" />
      <a href="#"><h3>{{item}}</h3></a>
   </li>
</ul>


<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Header',
    props:{},
    data() {
        return {
            items: ["Electronics", "Furniture", "Cloths", "Sports", "Entertainment", "Others"]
        }
    },
    methods:{
      getPicture(item){
          return  '@/assets/' + item + ".png"
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: You need to use `require`. Something like `return require('@/assets/' + item + '.png')`.

Comment: Also, don't use methods to render parts of your template. Try `:src="require(\`@/assets/${item}.png\`)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the data property

I think you should make array of object with name and src, then import every images.

```
<script>
import electronicSrc from "@/path/to/img/electronic";
import furnitureSrc from "@/path/to/img/furniture";

export default {
name: 'Header',
props:{},
data() {
    return {
         items = [{ category: "Electronics", src: electronicImg}, { category: "Furniture", src: furnitureImg}, { category: "Cloths", src: clothImg}, .. ];
    }
}, 
}
</script>
```

Modify the template

```
<li v-for="item in items" :key="item" class="center align-self-center">
  <img class="float-left" :src="item.src" v-bind:alt="item.category" />
  <a href="#"><h3>{{ item.category }}</h3></a>
```

Comment:  Also might be nice to make an `index.js` file that exports all the image modules

Comment: Yeah, @Phil right, thanks!